# switching focus between datagridview and button on form

Tags: c#

In my datagridview, sometimes I need to have focus off the datagridview and set the focus to next available control on the form. How to do this?

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';");
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click on select row";
            e.Row.Attributes["OnClick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.SingleSelectGrid, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);


            LinkButton selectbutton = new LinkButton()
            {
                CommandName = "Select",
                Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text
            };
            e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(selectbutton);
            e.Row.Attributes["OnClick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(selectbutton, "");


        }
```

Comment: Have you even tried searching for an answer before posting this question?  I'm down voting because your question doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: What do you call "next available control" ? this control may not be focusable. For example, it is the case for a label or a Disabled control.

Comment: @rory.ap yes sorry for it i was new in programming and need help soon that time so post question for which i easily got solution on internet. Apologized for same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on Control.SelectNextControl() and Control.Focus(). The rest is up to you...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Why? Is a "good" answer a fully running code exampel only? In my point of view this is exactly what @kish needs, As we do not know, why the OP needs this (maybe just a dirty to do something like "exit edit mode")... a "real" exampel is of no use...

Comment: If you don't know what the OP needs, then don't answer, otherwise it's pure guesswork and a waste of time for everyone involved.

Comment: The OP wants to "have focus off the datagridview and set focus to next available control on the form" This is no guesswork! But EOT for me, this is getting petty, happy coding anyway